# fit long equation into one line

Tags: subequations

I think this equation will fit into one line, but I'm running out of space in the editor. I don't want to split the equation (I don't think I will need to)

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\nu_{p} 
& =\frac{\partial V_{c}}{\partial \sigma_{p}}\\
&=PN'(d1)\frac{\partial d1}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\sigma_{p}}\\
&\ -GHN'(d2)\frac{\partial d2}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma_{p}}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a MWE? Otherwise, we cannot judge whether it will fit on one line.

Comment: Hi Karlo - relatively new to this. I posted the equation that I'm trying to write...not sure how to create a MWE. I'll explore that.

Comment: AboAmmar - that's perfect; worked great, thanks sir!

Comment: A MWE (minimal working example) means a complete piece of code that we can run to see the problem. If you only give the code `\begin{subequations}...\end{subequations}`, we do not know if we will have the same result if we add a documentclass etc. And it just saves time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not sure what you mean by running out of space in the editor, you can write the equation on as many lines as you want in the editor not leaving blank lines.

```
\begin{align}
\nu_{p} &=\frac{\partial V_{c}}{\partial \sigma_{p}} \notag\\
&=PN'(d_1)\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial\sigma}\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial\sigma_p}-GHN'(d_2)\frac{\partial d_2}{\partial\sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial\sigma_p}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: AboAmmar - that's perfect; worked great, thanks sir! – Chet just now   edit   
add a comment

Comment: @Chet Welcome to SE. If this answer solved your problem, do not forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it all fits in one line. I also suggest you simplify typing partial differentials with the `\diffp` command, from `esdiff`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, esdiff}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \nu_{p}
    =\diffp{V_{c}}{{\sigma_p}}
    =PN'(d1)\diffp{d1}{σ}\diffp{σ}{{\sigma_p}}
    \ -GHN'(d2)\diffp{d2}{σ}\diffp{σ}{{\sigma_p}}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]